# How to configure sendmail (or postfix) to send confirmation emails using webmin?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, sendmail

have a centos 5.5 64 bit xen vps. I have a php script that automatically sends confirmation emails for people who sign up, it's not sending it right now, I've been told to install webmin, and then install sendmail or postfix and configure it to send emails

I installed webmin, installed sendmail, and now what? if you know how to configure postfix then I'll unintall sendmail and install postfix.

I just want to send emails automatically, the confirmation mail, the welcome email and the goodbye email, and the reset password email, the email that i want to use is 
do-not-reply@example.com

I do not want to have an inbox i can use google apps email service to do so, just want to send automated emails

**NOTE**

I can do it via ssh, without webmin, just wanna know how, any tutorial or explanation would be so appreciated.

if you know how to configure another software similar to posftix and sendmail, I have no problem using it rather than using those 2. Basically I don't care what email server I use, as long as the job gets done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to Servers > Sendmail Mail Server. (If you don't see it, click Refresh Modules toward the bottom.)

In most cases you shouldn't need much configuration. PHP's [mail()](http://php.net/mail) function should work once sendmail is installed and running.

If it still doesn't work, could you:

1. describe how your application sends mail (and/or post the code)
2. describe what you see on Webmin's sendmail page esp. errors if there are any
3. send a message to yourself from the command line using the mail command and describe the result

Answer (score 2):

It's nothing easier than installing Postfix from command line. Just install it with your favorite package manager `yum install postfix`. After that you configure it as described in the [basic configuration readme](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html).

If you think that this is too hard and not easy enough you should not install a mail server. Not knowing what you do will probably exposes the mail server to the public and will harm other innocent people (sending Spam).

On the other hand I do not understand is why people don't use a search engine for these basics? First search hit reveals this complete HOWTO: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postfix
(This is 10 seconds work instead of 10 minutes writing this question).

Comment: i can install easily (i have webmin remember? and I can google), that's not my question, my question is similar to this one  http://bit.ly/r86vQT but didn't want you to read hundreds of line of code, so didn't talk about it,so i opened a ticket on clip-bucket, lets see what they say

Comment: @Eli so have you read [this](http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#null_client)? This is a 5 line configuration to do it.

Comment: thank you sir, I will remove sendmail, install postfix and follow the document :D